# Delete full workspace or one variable in julia

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I have searched for a while and experimenting with CommonRLInterface https://github.com/JuliaReinforcementLearning/CommonRLInterface.jl. There are some mutable variables. I am not an expert in Julia Programming, but I want to clear the whole workspace or delete a mutable variable (which is not allowed for mutable variables as far as I understand it, but in CommonRLInterface it comes from AbstractEnv superclass so I cannot change it).

```
struct myEnv <: AbstractEnv 

julia> myGridWorld=Nothing
ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant myGridWorld
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ none:1
```

I want to clear the whole workspace. So I have to stop julia and restart it again. In addition I have to activate the environment again.

It would help me if there would exist a button or keyshortcut, which automatically resets the workspace, starting a new julia kernel if necessary and activates the last environment (maybe also restarting the code).

There exists similar posts which were not helpful
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-clear-variables-and-or-whole-work-space/10149

Comment: I don't think such a feature exists in Julia (though I've expressed interest in it myself in the past, and also remember seeing some Github issue with discussion about maybe implementing this in the future). However, an important question is what your reason for seeking this feature is - you mentioned CommonRLInterface.jl, but it's not clear how exactly it factors into this, and what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Funny enough, this actually _used to exist_ pre Julia-1.0 https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6/stdlib/base/#Base.workspace

Comment: In the end I think I convinced myself it was better to design ones code and workflow such that you don't need it anyways, but nonetheless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open issue in Julia. See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/clear-workspace-a-la-pluto/74484 for a description of the current status of it.

A current partial solution for this is https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/workflow-tips/#A-basic-editor/REPL-workflow.

Essentially - do not load your code into `Main` module, but create a custom module where you load your code. Then you will be able to replace this custom module in a single session.