# Equivalent of R's `rm(list=ls())` in Julia

Tags: r, list, environment-variables, julia

Is there any equivalent to `R`'s `rm(list=ls())` (which removes every object in the global environment) in Julia?

Comment: Exactly the same question has been recently answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800177/delete-full-workspace-or-one-variable-in-julia/70800602

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I missed that. I will keep this question open so it can redirect `R` users in the future. Thank you very much, @BogumiłKamiński

Comment: Using `rm(list = ls())` is not a good idea in the first place.  It won't necessarily give you a fresh vanilla instance of R.

Comment: Sure - no problem with missing the other question. I will reopen your question as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible. See [Delete full workspace or one variable in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800177/delete-full-workspace-or-one-variable-in-julia/70800602) for the explanation of the current status of the issue (in short - the currently recommended practice is to wrap the code you use in a module and Julia will allow you to replace this module).